# Update text widget in tkinter from function

Tags: python, function, tkinter, widget

**The problem:**

I am trying to update the same text widget box from a function that contains some text. Instead a whole new text window appears every time.

**Here is my code:**

```
from tkinter import *
import os

#Tkinter graphics

homepage = Tk()
homepage.title("My first GUI")
# set size of window
homepage.geometry('1200x400')
# Add image file 
bg = PhotoImage(file = "maxresdefault.png") 
    
# Show image using label 
label1 = Label( homepage, image = bg) 
label1.place(x = 0, y = 0) 

label2 = Label( homepage, text = "Test App") 
label2.pack() 

# Create Frame 
frame1 = Frame(homepage) 
frame1.pack()

#button initatiors
def buttonupdate():
    S = Scrollbar(homepage)
    T = Text(homepage, height=100, width=30)
    T.pack()
    T.pack(side=RIGHT, fill= Y)
    S.pack(side = RIGHT, fill = Y)
    S.config(command=T.yview)
    T.insert(END, "test")
    T.config(yscrollcommand=S.set, state=DISABLED)


    

# Static buttons
tickets30button = Button(text = "This is button 1", command=buttonupdate) 
tickets30button.place(x=0, y=26) 

mcibutton = Button(text = "This is button 2") 
mcibutton.place(x=0, y=52)

hdebutton = Button(text = "This is button 3")
hdebutton.place(x=0, y=78)

homepage.mainloop()
```

Here is the result if I click on the first button three times:
[image]

Let me know if you have any suggestions that I can try.

Thank you for your time,

Comment: You create a new `Text` widget every time the function is called. Move first 5 lines from the function outside the function and it should work

Comment: Also why are you calling `T.pack()` and then `T.pack(side=RIGHT, fill= Y)`? Just have the `T.pack(side=RIGHT, fill= Y)`.

Comment: @TheLizzard that totally worked. I deleted the T.Pack() and took out the first five lines from the function and put it above the function and it works! The text widget will appear before I click the button now but that is cool with me if it doesn't keep making new windows every time. lol Thanks again.

Comment: You can delete this question or answer it or @TheLizzard can answer it.

Comment: @CoolCloud In my opinion it isn't good practise to delete the question. Other people might have the same problem and stumble upon this question and find a solution even if it is in the comments.

Comment: @TheLizzard Not really, there are ALOT of similar questions here already on this topic. I myself has answered ton of em.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to update my text window instead of create a new one, upon each click of a button, thanks to @TheLizzard.

He mentioned to move the section of code that creates the text window outside of the function and keep the section of code that creates the text, inside the function.

Before:

```
#button initiators
def buttonupdate():
    S = Scrollbar(homepage)
    T = Text(homepage, height=100, width=30)
    T.pack()
    T.pack(side=RIGHT, fill= Y)
    S.pack(side = RIGHT, fill = Y)
    S.config(command=T.yview)
    T.insert(END, "test")
    T.config(yscrollcommand=S.set, state=DISABLED)
```

After: (UPDATED)

```
S = Scrollbar(homepage)
T = Text(homepage, height=100, width=30)
T.pack(side=RIGHT, fill= Y)
S.pack(side = RIGHT, fill = Y)
S.config(command=T.yview)
T.config(yscrollcommand=S.set, state=DISABLED)

#button initatiors
def myTicketstatusbutton():
    T.delete(1.0,END)
    T.insert(END, "test")
```

Comment: Also you can move the `S.config(command=T.yview)` and the `T.config(yscrollcommand=S.set, state=DISABLED)` outside of your function to make it faster.

Comment: Also the `T.pack_forget()` isn't doing anything so you can remove it (it will have no effect on the actual code)

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot to remove that `T.pack_forget()` . Thanks for catching that.

Also I changed the answer to reflect the new information. Thanks again!